# get greatest prime factor in F#

Tags: f#

I had VS 11 beta and the following code was working without problem:

```
let rec fac x y =
    if x = y then y
    elif x % y = 0I then fac (x / y) y
    else fac x / (y + 1I)
```

Now I installed VS 2012 RC and I get the following error:

```
The type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger -> System.Numerics.BigInteger' is not compatible with the type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger'
```

Is code not correct or F# interactive? It's F# 3.0.

**EDIT**:

Actually problem not in F#, but in my code, it should be:

```
else fac x (y + 1I)
```

I just saved wrong version, when I worked in VS 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fac` expects two numbers, so when you have `fac x`, it isn't a number and thus cannot be divided by a number.

Comment: it seems that it wouldn't have worked under VS 11 beta either.  Maybe Alex added in the '/' operator at some point without remembering?  If so, maybe the question should be updated to reflect that, as otherwise it could be misleading.

Comment: @mattgately Any future visitor could read the short question, short answer and short comment by Alex and understand what happened here. I do not think there is any need for an edit, also can't remember seeing a precedent for that.